# Open two forms at the same time

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, applicationcontext

I have found an awesome solution for it, but it is written to work on app start, and I want to do it on a button click. It works, but enables the main form to be active too, and now I can open the 2 forms as many times as I want. Well it is not a desired feature. How can I lock the main form while the two forms are active? And another thing, we added the ESC key to close the form. When the forms were opened separately the ESC worked, now as both are opened at the same time we could press ESC all day and won't do a thing.

Below is the code I used:

```
public class MultiFormContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private int openForms;
    public MultiFormContext(params Form[] forms)
    {
        openForms = forms.Length;

        foreach (var form in forms)
        {
            form.FormClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                //When we have closed the last of the "starting" forms, 
                //end the program.
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref openForms) == 0)
                    ExitThread();
            };

            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

And I create the two forms from the main form like this:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        using (new MultiFormContext(new fmUgyek(), new fmNaptar()))
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    Form3 frm3 = null;

    frm2.Shown += (s, args) =>
    {
        frm3 = new Form3();
        frm3.Show();
    };

    frm2.FormClosing += (s, args) =>
    {
        frm3.Close();
    };

    frm2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

`Form2` is shown using `ShowDialog` which will prevent `Form1` from getting selected.  When `Form2` is shown, it shows `Form3` in its `Shown` event.  If `Form2` is closed, it will also close `Form3`.